# In app purchase rejection reason meaning?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

> 11.3 We found that your app allows users to purchase physical goods using In App Purchase, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

What does this mean?

I have an application which is using a nonrenewable subscription of 1 year for some content + consultation but my app is rejected due to the above reason. The Platinum Membership also offers a consultation feature. Are they referencing the consultation part of the in-app purchase when they reference that part of the review guidelines?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sell anything that cannot be consumed within the app. I'm assuming this "consulting" service that you're selling is not consumable within the app.

Comment: i want to know is that is making the pbm?removing it wiil solve the issue?

Comment: If the consultation service is not something that the user receives  and interacts with through the app, then it is not allowed and you need to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

There are four supported categories of In-App Purchase items that you may sell:

• Content

• Functionality

• Services

• Subscriptions

Also you should read [In-App Purchase Guidelines](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=iphone%20in%20app%20purchase%20rules&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFUQFjAA&url=https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf&ei=hyzYT8TwJ8esrAfZ19HRDw&usg=AFQjCNGZpPYRSW0LT8f9fxwyCNRtcKBNOA&cad=rja).